# How to push a JSON object to a nested array in a JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I need to somehow push a JSON object to a nested array of potentionally existing JSON objects - see "pages" in the below JSON snippet.

```
{
    "session_id": "someuuid",
    "visitor_ui": 1,
    "pages": [
        {
            "datetime": "2016-08-13T19:45:40.259Z",
            "duration,": 0,
            "device_id": 1,
            "url": {
                "path": "/"
            }
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2016-08-14T19:45:40.259Z",
            "duration,": 0,
            "device_id": 1,
            "url": {
                "path": "/test"
            }
        },
        // how can i push a new value (page) here??
    ]
    "visit_page_count": 2
}
```

I'm aware of the `jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb[, create_missing boolean])` (although still finding it a bit hard to comprehend) but I guess using that, would require that I first `SELECT` the whole JSONB column, in order to find out how many elements inside "pages" already exists and what index to push it to using `jsonb_set`, right? I'm hoping theres a way in Postgres 9.5 / 9.6 to achieve the equivalent of what we know in programming languages eg. `pages.push({"key": "val"})`.

What would be the best and easiest way to do this with Postgresql 9.5 or 9.6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick to `jsonb_set()` is that it modifies part of a `jsonb` object, but it returns the entire object. So you pass it the current value of the column and the path you want to modify ("pages" here, as a string array), then you take the existing array (`my_column->'pages'`) and append `||` the new object to it. All other parts of the `jsonb` object remain as they were. You are effectively assigning a completely new object to the column but that is irrelevant because an `UPDATE` writes a new row to the physical table anyway.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = jsonb_set(my_column, '{pages}', my_column->'pages' || new_json, true);
```

The optional `create_missing` parameter set to `true` here adds the "pages" object if it does not already exist.

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much - also great you took the time to explain it in more detail, since I wasn't able to figure it out from reading the docs. :-)

Comment: Glad to help and, yes, the docs can be a hard read sometimes, especially these tables where functions are described. I'll put this one in SO Documentation with more elaboration.

Comment: Is there a way to set the "pages" property IF it does NOT exist? Without having to do a separate update first?

Comment: `jsonb_set()` has an optional `create_missing` parameter which you can use. Just add `, true` to the function call; see updated answer.

Comment: Hi again Patrick. Thanks, but I can't get it to work. It's not that important though, since I can just do something like: `select coalesce(data, '{}'::jsonb ) || '{"pages": [{"url":"test"}]}'::jsonb from my_table` but it would have been very cool, had it worked :)