# Update Nested JSON Components in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
parts
id     name       children
1      Part 1     [{id: 2, name: 'Part 2'}]
2      Part 2     []
```

Let's say I change the name of `Part 2` to `Part X`

I want to update both the main data, and the nested children data.

I did this:

`UPDATE parts SET name = 'Part X' WHERE id=2`

Now how do I also update the JSON data to match?

I thought this was good syntax, but it's not:

`UPDATE parts SET [{name: 'Part X'}] WHERE json_agg([id: 2])`

Also this is `Postgres v10`

Comment: Have you seen the array functions? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Yes but i'm not sure how to update the specific object inside of the array

Comment: Don't have time atm to make a full answer, but hopefully this post gets you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941531/how-to-push-a-json-object-to-a-nested-array-in-a-jsonb-column