# How to append to a nested array in a JSONB column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Accepted answers elsewhere ([How to push a JSON object to a nested array in a JSONB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941531/how-to-push-a-json-object-to-a-nested-array-in-a-jsonb-column)) aren't working in my situation.

I want to append a string to a nested array in a not null JSONB column.  If the array doesn't exist, I want to create it (and have my string added).  The content of the column before the update happens will be an object `{}` (ie not an array).

The following just results in a *null value in column "data" violates not-null constraint* constraints error:

```
update md_ticker
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{labels}', data -> 'labels' || '"some string"', true)
where id = 74650534
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case` to check whether the `labels` array exists:

```
update md_ticker
set data = case 
    when data ? 'labels' then 
        jsonb_set(data, '{labels}', data -> 'labels' || '"some string"', true)
    else
        data || '{"labels": ["some string"]}'
    end
where id = 74650534
```